# Entity Framework Core self referencing entity JSON response

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 3.0 Web API project and I'm using Entity Framework as my ORM. I have a self referencing entity that looks like this:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Event>();
        InverseParentCategory = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> InverseParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the action method in my `CategoriesController` that returns all the categories as a JSON object:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllCategories()
    {
        var allCategories = await _categoryService.GetCategories();
        return Ok(allCategories);
    }
```

And this is my `GetCategories` method in my `CategoryService`:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetCategories()
    {
        var allCategories = await _context.Categories.ToListAsync();
        return allCategories;
    }
```

The response that I get through Postman is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Soccer",
        "parentCategoryId": null,
        "parentCategory": null,
        "events": [],
        "inverseParentCategory": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Basketbal",
                "parentCategoryId": 1,
                "events": [],
                "inverseParentCategory": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Volleyball",
                "parentCategoryId": 1,
                "events": [],
                "inverseParentCategory": []
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "",
                "parentCategoryId": 1,
                "events": [],
                "inverseParentCategory": []
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "dada",
                "parentCategoryId": 1,
                "events": [],
                "inverseParentCategory": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Basketbal",
        "parentCategoryId": null,
        "parentCategory": null,
        "events": [],
        "inverseParentCategory": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Basketbal",
        "parentCategoryId": 1,
        "parentCategory": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Soccer",
            "parentCategoryId": null,
            "parentCategory": null,
            "events": [],
            "inverseParentCategory": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Volleyball",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "dada",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "events": [],
        "inverseParentCategory": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Volleyball",
        "parentCategoryId": 1,
        "parentCategory": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Soccer",
            "parentCategoryId": null,
            "parentCategory": null,
            "events": [],
            "inverseParentCategory": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Basketbal",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "dada",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "events": [],
        "inverseParentCategory": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "",
        "parentCategoryId": 1,
        "parentCategory": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Soccer",
            "parentCategoryId": null,
            "parentCategory": null,
            "events": [],
            "inverseParentCategory": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Basketbal",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Volleyball",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "dada",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "events": [],
        "inverseParentCategory": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "dada",
        "parentCategoryId": 1,
        "parentCategory": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Soccer",
            "parentCategoryId": null,
            "parentCategory": null,
            "events": [],
            "inverseParentCategory": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Basketbal",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Volleyball",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "",
                    "parentCategoryId": 1,
                    "events": [],
                    "inverseParentCategory": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "events": [],
        "inverseParentCategory": []
    }
]
```

So you can see that when a child has a parent it return the parent's data and its children. I want to avoid this but I can't actually think of anything. Can I get any help?

Comment: What exactly do you want it to return?

Comment: Define a class that you suits your View (a ViewModel) and use `Select` or Automapper to project the entities into that ViewModel. Sending entities to views is wasteful, and potentially dangerous.